# Fixed spacing command for text

Tags: spacing

Currently im updating my CV.
Now i have something like this as output 
[image]

but i want something like (but with the exact same distance between the freespace

[image]

I tried with \quad but that didnt do the trick. I just want a very small tabulator  style format. 
with \quad i get the spacing for one line like i want to but it didnt fit the next like. The -- are not in "one column"-style?

Sorry for bad englisch, iam not a native speaker

Im using the "twentysecondcv" (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-resume-slash-cv/mhyfwrmwjkbc ) for the style of my CV. Here is a very basic example from the template. Now i want that the diffrent dates are on the same level like Apr.17 on one level than the - on another and the Sept.17 on a third. in the next like /twentyitembox i want that Okt.17 is directly under Apr.17 and the next - under the - of the line above...

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Twenty Seconds Resume/CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (8/1/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Carmine Spagnuolo (cspagnuolo@unisa.it) with major modifications by 
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% The MIT License (see included LICENSE file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4

\profilepic{alice.jpeg} % Profile picture

\cvname{} % Your name
\cvjobtitle{} % Job title/career

\cvdate{ } % Date of birth
\cvaddress{ } % Short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvnumberphone{ } % Phone number
\cvsite{ } % Personal website
\cvmail{ } % Email address

\begin{document}
\aboutme{}
\skills{}
\skillstext{}
\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

\section{Education}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{Apr.65-today}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
    \twentyitem{Mrz.65-Sept.65}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
    \twentyitem{Mai.61-Jun.63}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Se, could you please provide a MWE. Without which its really hard to help/ understand what is happening beneath your figure.

Comment: @Raaja i updated the question. I hope that helps

Comment: You can use `\makebox[width][pos]{text}` to put the date in a fixed with box. Something like `\makebox[7em][l]{Apr.\ 65}--today`. Adjust the width to your liking.

Comment: That CV was extesively modified and can be sourced here https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv e and its support page is here https://latex.org/forum/tag/twenty-seconds-resumecv

Comment: This question of increasing space for months was raised as an issue against the source and the answer was "not possible" and closed see https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex/issues/4